# What is the correct technique for calking two adjoining surfaces in a shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, caulking

I have an old shower where the base pan and the shower tiles come and meet nearly exactly aligned. There are sections in the shower where the tile has almost no gap and it varies to about 1/16th of an inch. I say this to show that there is no way to simply place the calk directly in the crack and call it a day. What is the proper way to do this? I've looked for examples on technique but nearly every example is at a 90 or near 90 degree angle.

Comment: Pictures are always a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, YouTube is great at showing the easiest of circumstances. What has worked for me is cutting the caulk nozzle straight across instead of at the 45 degree angle they suggest. Cut at the tip for the smallest opening and then press the caulk tube firmly against the tile seam at 90 degrees and start caulking. Move the tube slowly along the seam. If some caulk squirts out don't worry about it, wait until you're done with that section and then clean/smooth the seam with your finger, working more caulk into the seam. It will get easier once you get to the larger gaps. If you can weight the shower pan down you might be able to widen the gap before caulking.

Comment: The correct technique took me +10y to learn how to not need your finger, not that I don't still need to sometimes.

Comment: A big tip to anybody who isn't an expert caulker: When using this technique, definitely use masking tape all around the area before hand. Using your finger along the crack, it's hard to determine how much you will need. It helped to use extra and make a mess and then smooth it off around the edges of the tape. Having the double wide for me was a very helpful. It looked like a disaster, and then when I pulled the tape off, it looked amazing. Be sure to check your tape is firmly pressed down before starting too and be sure to pull the tape soon before it starts to dry.